# Break down weekly values into daily values using a profile in r

Tags: r

I have weekly values that I want to break down according to a profile vector.
Assume my weekly Data is:

```
data <- data.frame(Week = c(1, 2), Values = c(100, 1000))
```

and the profile and workdays are:

```
profile <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1)
days <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

What I want my output to look like is the following:

```
result <- data.frame(Day = c('1_1','1_2','1_3','1_4','1_5','2_1','2_2','2_3','2_4','2_5'),
                     output = c(10,20,20,40,10,100,200,200,400,100))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can replicate the rows of 'data' by `length` of 'days', then `paste` the 'Week', 'days' vector, while multiplying the 'Values' and 'profile' vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   uncount(length(days)) %>% 
   transmute(Day = str_c(Week, days, sep="_"), output = Values * profile)
#   Day output
#1  1_1     10
#2  1_2     20
#3  1_3     20
#4  1_4     40
#5  1_5     10
#6  2_1    100
#7  2_2    200
#8  2_3    200
#9  2_4    400
#10 2_5    100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand_grid()` in `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  expand_grid(Day = days) %>%
  transmute(Day = paste(Week, Day, sep = "_"), output = Values * profile)

# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#    Day   output
#    <chr>  <dbl>
#  1 1_1       10
#  2 1_2       20
#  3 1_3       20
#  4 1_4       40
#  5 1_5       10
#  6 2_1      100
#  7 2_2      200
#  8 2_3      200
#  9 2_4      400
# 10 2_5      100
```